# Cannot update repository Windows Azure

Tags: eclipse, azure, cloud

I'm trying Windows Azure now.
I have been following instruction from 
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/java-home/download-the-windows-azure-sdk-for-java/

I'm running on eclipse helios, but when i try to install new software and enter url repository :http://dl.windowsazure.com/eclipse

Eclipse always timeout,

message on message box like bellow :

```
Unable to connect to repository http://dl.windowsazure.com/eclipse/content.xml
Unable to connect to repository http://dl.windowsazure.com/eclipse/content.xml
Connection timed out: connect
```

How to solve this, i very need it to deploy my first app on Windows Azure platform

Help me to solve this, please

---

Now i try to runnning azure project on Cloud Azure, but why when i try to upload cspkg file and cscfg file, the process always timeout, whereas connection is running normally when i look on ping -t

this is message when i try upload on azure hosting service :

Uploading the selected package has failed, please verify your network connection and try again.

How to solve this issue ?
it's very strange error. >-<

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community. I suggest you spend some time looking at other questions and answers to better familarize yourself with the format. For some reason, you've chosen to create multiple answers as responses to people, which is something you shouldn't do. You should either edit your original question with additional info, or create comments under other peoples' answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with your network connection as I have just tested the same download location and it does work perfectly fine as below:

As you can see below I am using http://dl.windowsazure.com/eclipse URL to download the Java specific Azure components:

[image]

After that once I select "Next", the following two components are listed to be installed in my machine:

1. Microsoft JDBC Drive 3.0 for SQL Server (This will work with SQL Azure)
2. Windows Azure Plugin for Eclipse with Java

[image]

I am sure that the problem is specific to your network connection so please have it corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's foolish of me, i forget to shutting down my proxy server on  My compute.After i disable it,everything gonna be alright :D

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

surely I haven't meet this situation before , but just for your additional information..

Have you follow this step on installing azure @eclipse? like .net version must be >= 3.5

here are some source link for your help http://www.windowsazure4e.org/download/

Comment: try re-installing the windows azure on your eclipse then follow the step above

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t worked with Windows Azure Java SDK. But the error message is complaining the file C:\Users\workspace\AzureFirst\emulatorTools\ResetEmulator.cmd cannot be found. It would be better if you can check whether the file exists. In addition, the call stack points out you’re using Windows Azure SDK 1.4. Please try to upgrade it to 1.6 to see whether it works fine. You can find SDK 1.6 on http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28045. Please install WindowsAzureEmulator and WindowsAzureSDK. The WindowsAzureLibsForNet is not needed if you don’t want to use .NET.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.